# Changing UILabel background colour based on time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, colors, background, uilabel

I am developing an iPhone application in Xcode and Objective C.

What I am trying to achieve is changing the background colour for different labels based on the time of day.

I have several UILabels setup in the XIB file and set their background colour. In my .m file, I have then setup an action which runs every 3 seconds. A snippet of the code:

```
- (void)updateTime
{
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
    NSString *resultTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];

    if([resultTime compare:@"0819"] == NSOrderedDescending)
    { //IF THE TIME IS AFTER 0820AM
        if([resultTime compare:@"0850"] == NSOrderedAscending)
        { // IF THE TIME IS BEFORE 0850AM
            labelOne.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:160 green:160
                                                           blue:160 alpha:1.0];     
        }
    }
    if([resultTime compare:@"0849"] == NSOrderedDescending)
    { 
        if([resultTime compare:@"0945"] == NSOrderedAscending)
        { 
            labelTwo.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:160 green:160
                                                            blue:160 alpha:1.0];  
        }
    }
```

This seems to work at changing the background colour, however, when the if statement is meant to return false (it is not inside that time bracket), the background colour does not change back to what it is in the XIB file.

Could somebody please shed some light on how I can have different UILabels change colour when inside a certain time period.

Comment: I think you need to put else statements to put back the XIB file color back to labels

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly...not sure why I didn't think of it to begin with! derr :P


**FOR ANYBODY ELSE HAVING TROUBLE** _and for me when i forget!_
You have to convert the values for initWithRed, blue etc. to a number between 0.0 and 1.0 - so divide the 255 value (eg 129/255) and that is the value.